# Apex Class - List of records by record type that also reference a field value on found records

Tags: apex, list

I don't write code, so bear with me.

I have a portion of an Apex Class that pulls a list of record types for Cases. However, I need to add a criteria here that *then* looks at the received records and only includes the records where a certain field is filled in.

Current code:

```
List<RecordType> residentialRecordTypes = [SELECT Id
                                           FROM RecordType
                                           WHERE (DeveloperName = 'Residential' OR DeveloperName = 'Carpet' OR DeveloperName = 'Manufacturing_Distribution' OR DeveloperName = 'Residential_Service_Claims' OR DeveloperName = 'Mannington_Rubber')
                                           AND SobjectType = 'Case'
                                           AND Id in: casesByRecordTypeId.keySet()
                                           LIMIT 1];
```

So I essentially need to add something like:

`AND Case.Division__c LIKE 'Residential'`

Any idea how I would do this?

Thank you!

Melissa

Comment: You're looking at the wrong lines of code. The query you'd need to change is against `Case`, not `RecordType`. Although I'll also note that this RecordType query makes no sense and is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: You can get started with SOQL at [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql), but bear in mind that changes to Apex require changes to Apex tests in many cases, so you may need to work with a developer.

Comment: You dont need to query RecordType. It counts your SOQL Limit .So You have to Use Schema.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the code again and found the area where the initial criteria for where "List Case" (not record types) were being pulled from and I added my criteria there instead.

After some testing, it seems to be working.

```
        List<Case> casesToAssign = new List<Case>();

        for (Case newCase: caseRecordsToUpdate){
            Case oldCase = oldMap.get(newCase.Id);

            if (newCase.Status == 'Claim Authorized' && oldCase.Status != 'Claim Authorized' && newCase.Division__c.CONTAINS ('Residential') && (newCase.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Residential' || newCase.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Carpet' || newCase.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Manufacturing_Distribution' || newCase.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Residential_Service_Claims' || newCase.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Mannington_Rubber')){
                casesToAssign.add(newCase);
            }
```